# using wordpress plugins in magento possible?

Tags: wordpress, magento

I just had a little doubt..

can i use wordpress inside Magento CMS..... I mean can I able to install wordpress plugins in magento... The reason iam asking about Magento because, Iam gonna use magento templates and besides I also need to use wordpress plugins in it.. I need BOTH..

So, is this possible..?

While my research, I found some links, BUT still iam not clear on this..

here are some links I found:

```
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magento-wordpress-integration/
https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/magento-part-4-integrating-magento-and-wordpress-using-fishpig-extension
```

**So, can anyone pls clarify on this..?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use various Wordpress plugins inside Magento, short answer, as mentioned, is no.

With those link that you provide, you can achieve the following:

1. With wordpress plugin (link that you provided) you can have yourwordpress.com and then install Magento inside a folder, so Magento store would be available. for example, in yourwordpress.com/magentostore/ and you can easily display any Magento block(top links, categories, layered navigation block etc.) from your store in you Wordpress site.
2. With Magento plugin (I'd go with FishPig http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wordpress-integration.html) you can have opposite: yourmagentostore.com and than Wordpress blog/site inside blog folder of your Magento installation yourmagentostore.com/wordpressblog/ And there you'd be able to display footer and header of Magento in your wordpress site and display, for example, the latest blog post in Magento

agentoHope this help!

Comment: At first, thnx  a lot for ur breif answer... Actually I need to use one wordpress plugin MUST to develop a store and I have to use Magento template/theme as well... I feel there should be some alternative solution.. Donno what I have to do now.. :(

Answer (score 2):

Answer:no. You can't use WordPress plugins, which are specifically made for WordPress (and based on its framework) directly in Magento.

Comment: So with the help of those integration links given above by me, still after integration, still NOT possible using wordpress plugin in magento..?

Comment: No. The link you are mentionning is for a plugin that integrates Magento with WordPress in the way that it allows you to operate the two at the same time : you will be able to use WordPress functions as well as Magento functions in the same pages. But it does not go as far as making WordPress plugins compatible with Magento...

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use WordPress plugins with Magento.  They have wildly different architectures.

The integration articles you linked to are talking about using WordPress and Magento together on the same website.

You could theoretically write a plug-in for one that also manipulates the database used by the other, but that is likely a custom job, not something you can just go download somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

i think its impossible...because they have different backend architecture